# How do add List items to a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#

The code im trying wich is not working:

```
private void clearRichtextBox()
        {
            richTextBox2.Clear();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in LocalyKeyWords)
            {
                richTextBox2.AppendText("Url: " + kvp.Key + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + kvp.Value);
            }

        }
```

LocalyKeyWords is a List > type of Dictionary.
Where string is the Key and List is the Value.

http://www.google.com is the Key for example and google is the value.

Now in this case LocalyKeywords contain 3 indexs each one have a Key and a Value.
I want after i cleared the richTextBox2 to add from the List all the Keys and Values to the richTextBox in a Format like this:

```
Url: http://www.google.com --- Localy Keyword: google
Url: http://www.cnet.com --- Localy Keyword: cnet
Url: http://www.microsoft.com --- Localy Keyword: microsoft
```

But im not getting it the way i did it.

How can i do it ? Something wrong with the foreach i prefer to make it with FOR and not foreach.

The List is built as Key,Value in the text file on my hard disk fhr format is like this:

```
http://www.cnet.com,cnet
```

Then in the constructor im reading it from the text file and put back the key and value into the List like this:

```
private void richTextBoxLoadKeys(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string FileName)
        {
            string line = System.String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(keywords))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
                    dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
                    richTextBox2.AppendText("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
```

After loading the key and values in the constructor and using a breakpoint on the List i see:

[image]

Comment: your foreach is correct, maybe your LocalyKeyWords is defined incorrect. Using breakpoint during runtime check the values of LocalyKeyWords

Comment: Add the source of LocalyKeyWords class to your question

Comment: "*But I'm not getting it the way I did it.*"
What **are** you getting?

Comment: wasyl what im getting in the richTextBox is: System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]Url: http://www.cnet.com --- Localy KeyWord: cnet And what i wanted to see is only:  Url: http://www.cnet.com --- Localy KeyWord: cnet

Comment: Moshen the line of the LocalyKeywords List source im using is in the top of my Form1: Dictionary<string, List<string>> LocalyKeyWords = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

Comment: I will update the question of how the List is built when i use a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Added an image of how the List looks like when using a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate through the kvp.Value,it is also a list so you have to add each item from the list in the richtextbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either iterate through the strings in Value or just report the first string in Value. What you are getting is the ToString() of a List.
I'm curious whether you really need a List for the value since your example only has one Local Keyword per key. Perhaps you should be creating a Dictionary instead.